# Thread State In a Thread Pool

Tags: java, multithreading

I want to monitor memory leaks in ThreadLocals. To get all the thread local objects, I use the code from here http://blog.igorminar.com/2009/03/identifying-threadlocal-memory-leaks-in.html . This code uses a reflection to extract all the thread locals on current thread.

I want a background thread that monitors all threads.

It is simple to run over all threads (recursive calls on ThreadGroup). But, I need to know which threads are not currently running and still using the thread local objects.

For example:
Thread A uses LocalThread A1. After the thread is finished and returned to the thread pool of the container, A1 should be released.
Thread M is my monitoring thread. It runs over all the threads, and finds thread A. So, it needs to know whether A is not currently running because of a context switch (and is such case, A1 is not a leak), or A is not currently running because it was returned to the pool.

How can I distinguish between the cases?

BTW, my monitoring class need to support any platform (app servers, web servers, standard java, any vendor, java version 1.5 and above). It means that I need to know whether the thread is active, no matter if the container uses Executors framework or old threads mechanism....

Comment: I feel like I should point out that using the mechanism described in the linked article in combination with some long living monitoring thread can easily CREATE leaked references, causing the problem that you are trying to diagnose.  Take care to clean up references regularly and tread lightly.

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
for(Map.Entry<Thread, StackTraceElement[]> entry : Thread.getAllStackTraces()) {
    if (waitingOnTheRightLine(entry))
        checkThreadLocalValues(entry);
}
```

This would detect the exact line the thread is on to check its not running and its waiting at a known point.

Answer (score 1):

Sample code, hope it helps:

```
    Thread t = getYourThread();
    if(t.getState() != Thread.State.RUNNABLE)  {
       //currently the thread is not running...
    }
```